# What is the cleanest way to compare values of two lists composed of dictionaries, but those two lists may be different lengths?

Tags: python

So let's say I have two lists composed of dictionaries

```
list_a = [{"name": "bob", "age": 30}, {"name": "Sally", "age": 43}]
list_b = [{"name": "bob", "age": 31}, {"name": "John" , "age": 19}, {"name": "Sally", "age": 23}]
```

As you can see, these lists are of different lengths. I want to check whether the key value of "name:bob" is present in both lists, and if so, do something. If not, it can be ignored.

I've tried looping, but I run into an issue where the list index eventually becomes out of range due to the lists being of unequal lengths.

For example:

```
for x in range(len(list_a)): #can also be range of list_b
   if list_a[x]['name'] in list_b[x]['name']:
       do something & keep iterating 
   else:
       keep iterating
```

What is the cleanest way to go about this in python?

Comment: Is this some kind of JSON data or JSON-like?

Comment: If you ever write `range(len(some_list))`, you're doing it wrong.  `for item in some_list` and `for ix, item in enumerate(some_list)` are the ways to iterate over lists.  *(Also, your broken code only finds matches if the names are in the same positions in the lists.)*

Comment: @Makoto JSON has nothing to do with this, the OP has stated that they are lists of dictionaries. Of course, they didn't actually provide valid code, but it is pretty easy to understand what they have

Comment: If this is about "name:bob", why is that name not in your code?

Comment: @KellyBundy just an example. It's not only about bob, its about finding the similarities between two unequal length lists

Comment: @MatBailie thank you for your backhanded comments, definitely appreciated and in line with stackoverflow.

Comment: Apologies, was meant informatively, not patronisingly.

Comment: If you want something more general, then you need to say what. You haven't.

Comment: @KellyBundy understood, but I think the other commenters have caught on to what I was getting at. Will be more clear next time.

Answer (score 3):

A couple of alternatives using sets and comprehensions...

```
list_a = [{"name": "bob", "age": 30}, {"name": "Sally", "age": 43}, {"name": "Fredy", "age": 42}]
list_b = [{"name": "bob", "age": 31}, {"name": "John" , "age": 19}, {"name": "Sally", "age": 23}]
```

```
set_a = {dict_a.get("name") for dict_a in list_a}
set_b = {dict_b.get("name") for dict_b in list_b}
for name in set_a.intersection(set_b):
  print(name)
```

```
for name in [
  dict_a.get("name")
    for dict_a in list_a
    if dict_a.get("name") in {dict_b.get("name") for dict_b in list_b}
]:
  print(name)
```

Demo showing the differences in elapsed times: https://trinket.io/python3/57f4c83e22

Comment: appreciate the demo, thats really cool. Haven't seen that before

Comment: Wow, the demo is great! Question was about "cleanest way", not "fastest", so I didn't care about speed for small amount of data. Generally we should not do that.   For small lists (c.a. 100 elements each) my pandas solution is terrible. 2x slower than method2(), but over 7x faster than method3(). But when speed is important (list c.a. 4000 elements each) it's 137x faster than method2() and 480x faster than method3(). But still 14x slower than method1(). Very instructive demo, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Unless you specifically need the list indexes, it's cleaner to iterate over the values instead.

You can use two nested loops:

```
for a in list_a:
    for b in list_b:
        if a["name"] == b["name"]:
            # yes it is present in the other list
            # do stuff
```

Or, more pythonically, you can use the `any()` function along with a generator expression:

```
for a in list_a:
    if any(a["name"] == b["name"] for b in list_b):
        # yes it is present in the other list
        # do stuff
```

Of course this code will not find names that are not in `a` but are in `b`, but you can easily adapt it for that purpose.

Answer (score 0):

If your lists are very long, the cost of iterating over one to find if it matches a name from the other will take a lot of time (`O(len(list_a)*len(list_b))`). If you convert one of your lists into a more efficiently searchable data structure, you'll be able to quickly look up the names from the other list in it.

I suggest using a dictionary mapping from a name to either the associated age, or to the whole dict that contains both `name` and `age` keys (depending on what exactly you need in the "do something" part of your code.

```
dict_a = {item['name']: item['age'] for item in list_a}
for item in list_b:
    if item['name'] in listb:
        # do stuff with item['name'], item['age'] and dict_a[item['name']]
```

This should be much faster for large lists (`O(len(list_a)+len(list_b))`).

Comment: If this approach was extended to form both Lists into Dicts then the comparison could be done without a loop using such as `if dict_a.get('bob') and dict_b.get('bob'):`

Comment: @user19077881: That might be possible, it depends on whether the names are known separately from the data structures. If not, you don't really need to convert both of them, since you'll be iterating over the other one to find their matches.

Comment: Agreed,  but OP says `I want to check whether the key value of "name:bob" is present in both lists`

Answer (score 0):

Preparing data:

```
list_a = [{'name': 'bob', 'age': 30},{'name': 'Sally', 'age': 43}]
list_b = [{'name': 'bob', 'age':31}, {'name': 'John', 'age': 19}, {'name': 'Sally', 'age': 23}]
```

Isolate names from dictionaries:

```
names_a = [a['name'] for a in list_a]
names_b = [b['name'] for b in list_b]
```

Now you iterate names_a comparing existence in names_b:

```
for a in names_a:
    if a in names_b:
        print(a) # here you may do something
```

Output:
bob
Sally

Answer (score 0):

[John's reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75454343/6557808) looks like final. The cleanest possible implementation.
To not duplicate answers, let's try to do similar action with Pandas. Maybe (because of unknown reason in any other part of your code) it's good idea to use it instead of list of dictionaries?

---

tl;dr
You can shrink data preparation into 2 lines:

```py
df_merged = pd.merge(pd.DataFrame(list_a), pd.DataFrame(list_b), on="name")
df_merged = df_merged.set_index("name")

# example operation
df_merged['crazy_math'] = (df_merged['age_x'] - df_merged['age_y']) * 2
print(df_merged)
```

---

Now let me answer much longer, and a bit more descriptive way.

```py
import pandas as pd

list_a = [
    {"name": "bob", "age": 30},
    {"name": "Sally", "age": 43},
]
list_b = [
    {"name": "bob", "age": 31},
    {"name": "John", "age": 19},
    {"name": "Sally", "age": 23},
]

# lists to dataframes
df_a = pd.DataFrame(list_a)
df_b = pd.DataFrame(list_b)

# merge dataframes on the "name" column;
# by default, merge is done with `how="inner"`,
# so you'll get only these positions, you're looking for, i.e. the same "name"
df_merged = pd.merge(df_a, df_b, on="name")

# not nesesery, but true and makes things cleaner
df_merged = df_merged.set_index("name")

print(df_merged)
# Printed:
#     name  age_x  age_y
# 0    bob     30     31
# 1  Sally     43     23
```

Now the dataframe is ready to work with it. For example you can compute mean()

```py
print(df_merged.mean(axis=1))
# Printed:
# name
# bob      30.5
# Sally    33.0
```

or do whatever you want by hand. For example:

```py
df_merged['crazy_math'] = (df_merged['age_x'] - df_merged['age_y']) * 2

print(df_merged)
# Printed:
#        age_x  age_y  crazy_math
# name                           
# bob      30     31          -2
# Sally     43     23          40
```